# Formatting date javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using `var dateString= new Date(parseInt(dateStringUnix));` and I obtain a string as `Sun Jun 10 2012 16:40:16 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)`.

The question is: how can I remove string part `GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
dateString = dateString.toString().replace(/ GMT.*/,"");
```

The above just replaces space before `GMT`, and everything after `GMT` including `GMT` with empyt `String`.

I've used `.toString()` to convert `Object` to `String` so that `.replace()` can be used.

Comment: You'll actually need `dateString.toString().replace`, because even if the OP said string, it's still a `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Go for a simple but powerful library like moment.js . May not be needed if it is a small functionality in your project, but it is eventually a swiss army knife for date and related things

Answer (score 0):

This is my current favorite, because it's both flexible and modular. It's a collection of (at least) three simple functions:

```
/**
 * Returns an array with date / time information
 * Starts with year at index 0 up to index 6 for milliseconds
 * 
 * @param {Date} date   date object. If falsy, will take current time.
 * @returns {[]}
 */
getDateArray = function(date) {
    date = date || new Date();
    return [
        date.getFullYear(),
        exports.pad(date.getMonth()+1, 2),
        exports.pad(date.getDate(), 2),
        exports.pad(date.getHours(), 2),
        exports.pad(date.getMinutes(), 2),
        exports.pad(date.getSeconds(), 2),
        exports.pad(date.getMilliseconds(), 2)
    ];
};
```

Here's the pad function:

```
 /**
 * Pad a number with n digits
 *
 * @param {number} number   number to pad
 * @param {number} digits   number of total digits
 * @returns {string}
 */
exports.pad = function pad(number, digits) {
    return new Array(Math.max(digits - String(number).length + 1, 0)).join(0) + number;
};
```

Finally I can either build my date string by hand, or use a simple functions to do it for me:

```
/**
 * Returns nicely formatted date-time
 * @example 2015-02-10 16:01:12
 *
 * @param {object} date
 * @returns {string}
 */
exports.niceDate = function(date) {
    var d = exports.getDateArray(date);
    return d[0] + '-' + d[1] + '-' + d[2] + ' ' + d[3] + ':' + d[4] + ':' + d[5];
};

/**
 * Returns a formatted date-time, optimized for machines
 * @example 2015-02-10_16-00-08
 *
 * @param {object} date
 * @returns {string}
 */
exports.roboDate = function(date) {
    var d = exports.getDateArray(date);
    return d[0] + '-' + d[1] + '-' + d[2] + '_' + d[3] + '-' + d[4] + '-' + d[5];
};
```